# How can I update new version of Doctrine2 and ORM in symfony?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

How Can I update the version of Doctrine2 and ORM in my symfony project?

This question is because I have tried to update only one bundle but the console returns error, and I have to update all the bundles.

Thanks.

Comment: Before anybody set minus to this question, please, explain why you do it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `composer`. You can run next command:

```
php composer.phar update
```

Also composer try to update all your `requires` in `composer.json` file.

But if you only want to install or update one dependency, you can whitelist them:

```
php composer.phar update doctrine/orm
php composer.phar update doctrine/doctrine-bundle
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I can update only one bundle? in thes case only Doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

Run `composer update doctrine/*` to update all doctrine packages